Is every version of the plugin built and released?
I'm organizing the release process for my own project and would like to refer to Eclipse Project which has all the release versions listed here.
In version 4.33 site, there exists the plugin org.eclipse.e4.ui.progress_0.4.600.v20240606-1020.jar.
In version 4.32 site, there exists the plugin org.eclipse.e4.ui.progress_0.4.400.v20240424-0956.jar.
So it looks like there should be a plugin like org.eclipse.e4.ui.progress_0.4.500.v..., so where is it? Or is it not built, but just updated during internal development, i.e., version 0.4.500 of the plugin exists in the git repository and has not been released to the public?

See history of org.eclipse.e4.ui.progress/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF: yes, 0.4.400 -> 0.4.500 and 0.4.500 -> 0.4.600 happened between two releases, so 0.4.500 existed in builds, not in one of the quarterly releases.

Yes, 0.4.400 → 0.4.500 and 0.4.500 → 0.4.600 happened between two releases, so 0.4.500 existed in builds, not in one of the quarterly releases:
See the history of org.eclipse.e4.ui.progress/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF.
